# Angular 2 - binding not working

Tags: angular, data-binding

I am trying to display some simple data on the template, but this is not working. The final output shows as:

```
{{message}}
ID  Name
{{item.id}} {{item.name}}
```

Here is the code. What am I doing wrong?

**list.component.html**

```
{{message}}
<table >
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items" >
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**list.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Renderer, EventEmitter, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/list/list.component.html'
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

    public message:string;

    items: [{id: number, name: string}];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.message = "hello";
        this.loadList();
    }

    loadList() {
        console.log("hello2");

        this.items = [{ id: 1, name: "Test1" }];
    }

}
```

Comment: what is "vuln.id"? are you missing something in the example?

Comment: I have updated the code. it should be "item.id" and "item.name"

Comment: any error logs?

Comment: No error. Is there anything that needs to be imported for binding to work?

Comment: can you add your app.module.ts? also are you sure of your template path?

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
}